Unable To connect MS Fabric Data Warehouse using SSMS
I am using 60 days trail plan of Microsoft Fabric and in it I have created a new Data Warehouse and I want to access it using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) tool present on my VM.
When I try to access it is giving me below error. I don't understand how to fix this issue?

I added the port in the inbound port rule as well in the azure VM but still not able to connect the Fabric data warehouse using SSMS. Am i missing anything?


This is a DNS or outbound firewall issue.  Test with powershell: test-netconnection <sqlendpoint> -port 1433
